# Unstable attach function on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Flair` and a `Link` model, also I've created a migration named 'flair_link' to keep a relation between the two. Because Link can be `flairable` or not based on their `Category` which is also an another model.

This is my migration file for `create_flair_linl_table`:

```
Schema::create('flair_link', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('link_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('link_id')->references('id')->on('links');
    $table->integer('flair_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('flair_id')->references('id')->on('flairs');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

On the `LinkController.php` under `new()` function:

```
public function makeLink(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'url' => 'required|url',
        'category_id' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);

    $link = new Link;
    $link->title = $request->title;
    $link->url = $request->url;
    $link->user_id = Auth::id();
    $link->category_id = $request->category_id;
    if($request->flair) {
        // $link->attachFlair((int)$request->flair);
        // or
        $link->flairs()->attach(Flair::where('id', (int)$request->flair)->firstOrFail());
    };
    if( $link->save() ){
        return redirect()->route('link.show', [ 'id' => $link->id ]);
    }
}
```

Although when I use `tinker` to create relation between `$link` and `$flair` somehow it works weirdly:

```
$link = App\Link::find(1)
$flair = App\Flair::find(1)
$link->flairs()->attach($flair)
```

returns: `null` but when I check `$link->flairs` I can see that the `flair` is succesfully attached to the `link`.

Yet when I make the form like this:

```
<select name="flair">
    @foreach ($category->flairs as $flair)
        <option value="{{ $flair->id }}">{{ $flair->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This is what I get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: flair_link.link_id (SQL: insert into "flair_link" ("flair_id", "link_id") values (1, ))
```

Comment: I should mention that I have also tried making a function in `Link.php` model called `attachFlair($id)` so that I can use `flair_id` instead of `flair` model. Because I can only send a value (in this case the id of the flair) in `select` form in html.

Comment: How you instantiate the `$link` in this line _$link->flairs()->attach((int)$request->flair);_

Comment: That html code on top explains it. I have a select form that passes the id of the flair that is selected through the $request on controller. Since it passes as a string I change it to an Interger using `((int)$request->flair)`. `dd((int)$request->flair)` returns the expected result.

Comment: I added the full code on top. Sorry I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. In order for the `attach` function to work we need the model. I was calling the `attach` method before I saved the link. The solution is :

```
if( $link->save() ){
    if($request->flair) {
        $link->attachFlair((int)$request->flair);
        // or
        // $link->flairs()->attach(Flair::where('id', (int)$request->flair)->firstOrFail());
    };
    return redirect()->route('link.show', [ 'id' => $link->id ]);
}
```

Comment: That why I asked you from where you're getting the variable `$link`... Good job

Comment: Thanks. It's nice of you to make me think rather than stating the problem directly.